# How to expand an NSMenuItem programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

For example, I want to expand out the pull-down menu from an item in the main menu programmatically. I saw this [thread](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2007/Aug/msg00669.html) in 2007, which doesn't provide any solution..

Does anyone know how to do this task?

Comment: I guess it could be useful for tutorials, in-app help, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`popUpStatusItemMenu:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSStatusItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSStatusItem/popUpStatusItemMenu:) to show an NSStatusItem's NSMenu programmatically:

```
[statusItem popUpStatusItemMenu:menu];
```

Comment: the question is: "pull-down menu from an item in the main menu programmatically"